# Information about versioning in HEADER (Swagger)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I have a versioned REST API

In Swagger as on the attached screen we have information about the required header (Authorization)

Can you configure Swagger to also show information about the versioning header?

```
api-version: 1.0
```

Screen:

[image]

Comment: You've asked a question [every two days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11634985/netdev?tab=questions) for the month you've been a member. Please read [ask] and make sure you show your research. This question has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @CodeCaster Almost three years have passed since the answers. If you know a little about the case, you will certainly come up with the idea that there could be a lot of changes in that time

Comment: Have you tried it, or are you dismissing it merely based on age of the answers?